# Adding a role to a user via DMs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

The Discord bot is going to add a role to the user that sent the DM message.
Currently, I have the user's ID and I have the role ID. I don't know what steps I need to take in order to add the role to the user.

The messages are in a DM so I went and did this:

```
let userId = message.author;
somethingHere.addRole('roleId#');
```

What is that missing piece before the `.addRole` that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.addRole` is a method of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), so in order to use it you need to get the member object of that user (otherwise the bot couldn't know in which guild it should do it.)
If you have only one guild stored somewhere, you can do [`<Guild>`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)[`.member(message.author)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member)[`.addRole('role id')`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole), otherwise you'll need a way to figure out which guild they want the role in.

Comment: 1 Question before I tackle this, what was the code to get the members object of the user?

Comment: @Tril [`<Guild>.member(<User>)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) or, if you want the longer version, [`<Guild>.members.get(<User>.id)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members)

Comment: Thanks so much for the direction. I ended up getting it after! thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear that!